# transpose grouped rows into from-to columns in r

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns

I have one dataset and I would like to transpose these grouped rows into columns and calculate distance as well.

Let´s say I have a dataset like below
Where "order" column is only related within groups and there are many kinds of mod and one group use only one mod.
And of course dataframe has more rows with groups.

| Group1 | order | Area_id | start_date | end_date | mod | Area_name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | trk | California | 36.778261 | -119.4179324 |
| A | 2 | 0002 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-07 | trk | Californib | 36.778262 | -119.4179325 |
| A | 3 | 0003 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-12 | trk | Californic | 36.778264 | -119.4179329 |
| A | 4 | 0004 | 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-20 | trk | Californid | 36.778265 | -119.4179330 |
| B | 1 | 0012 | 2022-02-11 | 2022-02-12 | bus | Barcelona | 41.385063 | 2.1734036 |
| B | 2 | 0013 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-18 | bus | Barcelonb | 41.385064 | 2.1734037 |
| C | 1 | 0020 | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-29 | car | oaklanda | 37.8043237 | -122.2711133 |
| C | 2 | 0012 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-04 | car | Barcelona | 41.385063 | 2.1734036 |
| C | 3 | 0009 | 2022-02-07 | 2022-02-10 | car | oaklandc | 37.8043637 | -122.2711237 |

...
I would like to convert these dataframe like below.
Where "Distance" columns are distance between "From_area" and "To_area".
Could you please help?

| Group | From_area_id | To_area_id | From_area | To_area | start_date | end_date | mod | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0001 | 0002 | California | Californib | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | trk |  |
| A | 0002 | 0003 | Californib | Californic | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-10 | trk |  |
| A | 0003 | 0004 | Californic | Californid | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-16 | trk |  |
| B | 0012 | 0013 | Barcelona | Barcelonb | 2022-02-12 | 2022-02-14 | bus |  |
| C | 0020 | 0012 | oaklanda | Barcelona | 2022-01-29 | 2022-02-02 | car |  |
| C | 0012 | 0009 | Barcelona | oaklandc | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-07 | car |  |

Comment: But `From_area` and `To_area` are both character vectors, how do you want to compute the distance?

Comment: I thought there might be way to compute distance from the long & lat columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** after clarification: See comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group1) %>% 
  mutate(end_date1 = lead(start_date)) %>% 
  mutate(start_date = end_date, .keep="unused") %>% 
  mutate(Area_id = str_pad(as.character(Area_id), 4, pad="0")) %>%
  mutate(To_area_id = lead(Area_id), .after="Area_id") %>% 
  mutate(To_area = lead(Area_name), .after="Area_name") %>% 
  mutate(across(c(lat, long), ~lead(.), .names = "To_{.col}")) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  rename(end_date = end_date1, From_area_id = Area_id, From_area = Area_name, From_lat=lat, From_long = long) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Distance = distHaversine(c(From_long, From_lat), 
                                  c(To_long, To_lat)), .keep="unused") %>% 
  select(Group = Group1, From_area_id, To_area_id,
         From_area, To_area, start_date, end_date, mod, Distance)
```

```
  Group From_area_id To_area_id From_area  To_area    start_date end_date   mod      Distance
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
1 A     0001         0002       California Californib 2022-01-02 2022-01-04 trk         0.112
2 A     0002         0003       Californib Californic 2022-01-07 2022-01-10 trk         0.225
3 A     0003         0004       Californic Californid 2022-01-12 2022-01-16 trk         0.112
4 B     0012         0013       Barcelona  Barcelonb  2022-02-12 2022-02-14 bus         0.112
5 C     0020         0012       oaklanda   Barcelona  2022-01-29 2022-02-02 car   9572260.   
6 C     0012         0009       Barcelona  oaklandc   2022-02-04 2022-02-07 car   9572257.
```

**First answer:**

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

library(geosphere)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group1) %>% 
  mutate(Area_id = str_pad(as.character(Area_id), 4, pad="0")) %>%
  mutate(To_area_id = lead(Area_id), .after="Area_id") %>% 
  mutate(To_area = lead(Area_name), .after="Area_name") %>% 
  mutate(across(c(lat, long), ~lead(.), .names = "To_{.col}")) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  rename(From_area_id = Area_id, From_area = Area_name, From_lat=lat, From_long = long) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Distance = distHaversine(c(From_long, From_lat), 
                                  c(To_long, To_lat)), .keep="unused")
```

```
  Group1 order From_area_id To_area_id start_date end_date   mod   From_area  To_area       Distance
  <chr>  <int> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>            <dbl>
1 A          1 0001         0002       2022-01-01 2022-01-02 trk   California Californib       0.112
2 A          2 0002         0003       2022-01-04 2022-01-07 trk   Californib Californic       0.225
3 A          3 0003         0004       2022-01-10 2022-01-12 trk   Californic Californid       0.112
4 B          1 0012         0013       2022-02-11 2022-02-12 bus   Barcelona  Barcelonb        0.112
5 C          1 0020         0012       2022-01-27 2022-01-29 car   oaklanda   Barcelona  9572260.   
6 C          2 0012         0009       2022-02-02 2022-02-04 car   Barcelona  oaklandc   9572257.
```

Comment: Oh yes this one thank you though could you please check again start_date and end_date?  They should be also modified according to this from_area and to_area

Comment: Please see my update, now it should work.